# Backup using `rsync` fails because of a file that is not even into the source directory to be backed up

Tags: command-line, backup, rsync

I am trying to backup the `/User/user01/Library` using `rsync` (via the linux-timemachine wrapper `https://github.com/cytopia/linux-timemachine`) to an external hard drive `Volumes/name_of_backup` logged in as `user01`. During the backup I get the following error message

```
rsync warning: some files vanished before they could be transferred (code 24) at /System/Volumes/Data/SWE/macOS/BuildRoots/220e8a1b79/Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/rsync/rsync-55/rsync/main.c(996) [sender=2.6.9]
```

What I don't understand is that the file `/System/Volumes/Data/SWE/macOS/BuildRoots/220e8a1b79/Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/rsync/rsync-55/rsync/main.c` is not even located in the directory that I am trying to backup (namely `/User/user01/Library`). So why does this error appears?

Answer (score 3):

The error happens because some file(s) in `/User/user01/Library` was there when you started the backup, but were gone when `rsync` got around to copying it. You will have received a warning message about each such file during the backup.

The reference to `/System/Volumes/Data/SWE/macOS/BuildRoots/220e8a1b79/Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/rsync/rsync-55/rsync/main.c` just means that the code that output this error message came from that particular source code file. This is not the file that disappeared during backup.

Comment: ok many thanks for your answer @jksoergaard. I understand the root of the problem. The crucial question however now is how to get around this to be able to successfuly backup `User/user01/Library`?

Comment: @ecjb look at the names of the actual files. Most likely these are cache entries or temporary files not requiring backup anyway.

Comment: many thanks for your comment @nohillside. So I removed the subfolders `Caches` and `Cookies` from the backup with `--exclude="Caches" --exclude="Cookies"`but I noticed that during the backup, there seem to be cache being synced in many other subfolder. Identifiyng and excluding each one of them would probably result in a huge amount work and end up beeing a big mess. Do you have another advice?

Comment: @ecjb I‘m not sure the directories are even called like that. You should get a warning for each file which can‘t be accessed, this should give you a clue.

Comment: @ecjn If you are just excluding the files anyways, there's really not much of a point in handling this at all. You can just let the command proceed and ignore the warning about disappearing files.

Comment: many thanks @nohillside. I will try